# How can I solve this PHP login bug?

Tags: php

I have my HTML form's `action` attribute set to `auth/login.php`, which does exist. What it does is basically check if the fields are empty. If not, it checks against the SQL database for a username that was inputted into the field, finds the row, and verifies the password hash to make sure that it's the right password. It then redirects to `home.php`, but since it is in a different folder, must be `../home.php`.

**Expected:** Redirects to home.php
**Reality:** Upon form submission, does nothing but check if the fields are empty.

Any help is appreciated, here is the code:

```php
<?php
    # Authenticator

    include("../server/conn.php");
    
    $required = array('username', 'password');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $error = false;
        foreach($required as $field) {
          if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
            $error = true;
          }
        }
    
        if ($error) {
          header("Location: ../login.php");
        } else {
            $getuserpassword = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');
            $getuserpassword->bind_param("s", $_POST['username']);
            $getuserpassword->execute();
            $getres1 = $getuserpassword->get_result();
    
            if ($getres1->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $getres1->fetch_assoc()) {
                  $db_password = $row['password'];
            
                  if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $db_password)) {
                    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
                    $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['id'];
                    header("Location: ../home.php");
                  } else {
                      header("Location: ../login.php");
                  }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
?>
```

Comment: what exactly u get in $getres1 and $row , debug your code step to step to figure out the problem.

Comment: are you sure both the fields or the ``password`` form field is empty?

Comment: also, always call ``exit();`` after calling ``header("Location: ../login.php");``

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR;** Add this code below `header` function call:

`exit('<meta httpd-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=../login.php"/>');`

**Description**

Sometimes, there are some outputs those are already sent to client's browser and because of that, you cannot modify response headers anymore and you will receive a warning that says `Cannot modify headers. Headers already sent.` which may be invisible due to server `display_errors` and `error_reporting` configuration in `php.ini`.

This is generally a bug in server configuration but sometimes, it may be a problem in your script files. For example, if you have saved your files with `Windows Notepad`, it will add BOM (Byte Order Marks) to the beginning of your UTF-8 files. So you have better to use some other good text editors or IDE's (e.g. Notepad++, phpStorm, VSCode, etc.)

However, there are several workarounds for this problem:

1. You can enable output buffering on your server (php.ini):
   `output_buffering = on` or `output_buffering = 16384`
2. You can surround your code with `ob_start` and `ob_end_flush`:

```
ob_start();
// your code goes here
ob_end_flush();
```

3. In case you have used `header` just to redirect user to another page, add an `exit` call with a `meta` refresh tag and add delay and URL of target page:
   `exit('<meta httpd-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=../login.php"/>');`
   This way, if for any reason, `header` function cannot be executed, then your script will be stopped by `exit` call and then, `meta` tag which is sent to the browser will redirect user to your intended URL.

Answer (score 0):

you should add session_start() at the top when you are going to use the session.

```
<?php
# Authenticator
session_start();
include("../server/conn.php");

$required = array('username', 'password');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $error = false;
    foreach($required as $field) {
      if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
        $error = true;
      }
    }

    if ($error) {
      header("Location: ../login.php");
      exit();
    } else {
        $userName = $_POST['username'];
        $userNameSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM users where username='$userName'";

        $queryExecute = $conn->query($userNameSelectQuery );

        if($queryExecute){
            if(mysqli_num_rows($queryExecute)>0){
                foreach($queryExecute as $key=>$value){
                    $db_password = $value['password'];
                    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $db_password)) {
                        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
                        $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['id'];
                        header("Location: ../home.php");
                        exit();
                      } else {
                          header("Location: ../login.php");
                          exit();
                      }
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
?>
```